# Confusing Google Maps Exception: The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private field for the wrapped object

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

In my app I made a helper fragment extending `SupportMapsFragment` that can be initialized with predefined markers and will adjust its camera accordingly. Here's the implementation:

```
public class MarkerMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
            final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        init(v);
        return v;
    }

    private void init(final View v) {
        final GoogleMap map = getMap();

        if (map == null) {
            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    init(v);
                }
            }, 100);

            return;
        }

        final ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("markers");

        final LatLngBounds.Builder cameraPositionBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        for (final MarkerOptions marker : markers) {
            map.addMarker(marker);
            cameraPositionBuilder.include(marker.getPosition());
        }

        v.post(new Runnable() {
            private int trys = 3;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                trys--;

                final int height = v.getHeight();
                final int width = v.getWidth();

                if (height == 0 || width == 0) {
                    if (trys > 0) {
                        v.post(this);
                    }
                } else {
                    final LatLngBounds bounds = cameraPositionBuilder.build();
                    final CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width,
                            height, (int) ViewUtils.dipToPixels(v.getContext(), 40f));

                    map.moveCamera(update);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

All these checks and redundancies seem to be necessary to ensure the map is loaded and the view layouted. Nevertheless I get the following crash log from my users which I cannot reproduce:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.raumobil.android.busliniensuche/de.busliniensuche.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private field for the wrapped object.  Preferably, this is an instance of the ObjectWrapper<T> class.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1979)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2004)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4573)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private field for the wrapped object.  Preferably, this is an instance of the ObjectWrapper<T> class.
    at dby.a(SourceFile:76)
    at maa.a(Unknown Source)
    at maa.a(Unknown Source)
    at lxs.a(Unknown Source)
    at mbi.a(Unknown Source)
    at fms.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.getCameraPosition(Unknown Source)
                                                                moveCamera
                                                                animateCameraWithCallback
                                                                animateCameraWithDurationAndCallback
                                                                addPolyline
                                                                addPolygon
                                                                addMarker
                                                                addGroundOverlay
                                                                addTileOverlay
                                                                setMapType
                                                                setTrafficEnabled
                                                                setLocationSource
                                                                setOnCameraChangeListener
                                                                setOnMapClickListener
                                                                setOnMapLongClickListener
                                                                setOnMarkerClickListener
                                                                setOnMarkerDragListener
                                                                setOnInfoWindowClickListener
                                                                setInfoWindowAdapter
                                                                addCircle
                                                                setOnMyLocationChangeListener
                                                                setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener
                                                                snapshot
                                                                setPadding
                                                                setOnMapLoadedCallback
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.gM(Unknown Source)
                                          moveCamera
                                          addMarker
                                          setOnInfoWindowClickListener
    at de.busliniensuche.android.view.MarkerMapFragment.init(MarkerMapFragment.java:82)
    at de.busliniensuche.android.view.MarkerMapFragment.onCreateView(MarkerMapFragment.java:51)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1514)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4756)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1952)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private field for the wrapped object.  Preferably, this is an instance of the ObjectWrapper<T> class.
    at dby.a(SourceFile:76)
    at maa.a(Unknown Source)
    at maa.a(Unknown Source)
    at lxs.a(Unknown Source)
    at mbi.a(Unknown Source)
    at fms.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.getCameraPosition(Unknown Source)
                                                                moveCamera
                                                                animateCameraWithCallback
                                                                animateCameraWithDurationAndCallback
                                                                addPolyline
                                                                addPolygon
                                                                addMarker
                                                                addGroundOverlay
                                                                addTileOverlay
                                                                setMapType
                                                                setTrafficEnabled
                                                                setLocationSource
                                                                setOnCameraChangeListener
                                                                setOnMapClickListener
                                                                setOnMapLongClickListener
                                                                setOnMarkerClickListener
                                                                setOnMarkerDragListener
                                                                setOnInfoWindowClickListener
                                                                setInfoWindowAdapter
                                                                addCircle
                                                                setOnMyLocationChangeListener
                                                                setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener
                                                                snapshot
                                                                setPadding
                                                                setOnMapLoadedCallback
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.gM(Unknown Source)
                                          moveCamera
                                          addMarker
                                          setOnInfoWindowClickListener
    at de.busliniensuche.android.view.MarkerMapFragment.init(MarkerMapFragment.java:82)
    at de.busliniensuche.android.view.MarkerMapFragment.onCreateView(MarkerMapFragment.java:51)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1514)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4756)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1952)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2004)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4573)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is it supposed to mean and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: most likely you are trying to move the camera before the view is loaded so it is a race condition you are creating.

Comment: do you have updates on this issue?

Comment: Nope, just put even more try-catches around it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same exception, and can reproduce it as follows.

First, I should note that I am using SupportMapFragment directly, and obtaining the map via getMapAsync() and onMapReady().

In onMapReady() I am adding Markers from an ArrayList of MarkerOptions obtained from a savedInstanceState bundle (and I have checked to make sure the MarkerOption title and location fields are valid). I clear the map before adding the markers because sometimes the fragment comes back with the markers rebuilt for me, and sometimes it doesn't (depending on the time delay below).

Here's how I can reproduce this problem (on an LG G2):

With the app on screen, press the Android home button.

Turn off the device.

Wait awhile (if I don't wait long enough this problem doesn't occur).

Turn on the device.

Go to the recent apps list and select my app.

If I've waited long enough I get this exception at the addMarker() call:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private field for the wrapped object...

Oddly enough I can still add a marker from a newly created MarkerOption after that (via a click handler). So, I suppose I could try posting a message in order to delay the attempted addMarker() calls, but I haven't tried that yet.

The only other solution I've come up with is to call finish() in the catch, so that the app simply goes away if it relaunches with this problem. In my case the user then has to relaunch the app normally, and the markers get rebuilt because I save them as part of a local XML file that is parsed in onCreate() when there is no incoming state bundle. This is far from ideal so I'm hoping someone figures out a real solution.